# Local freeness of $\pi_*F(r)$ from flatness of $F$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, flatness

In 'Fundamental Algebraic Geometry' by Fantechi there is a lemma in section 5.3.2, page 119:

*LEMMA 5.5* Let $S$ be a noetherian scheme and let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n_S$. Suppose there exist some integer $N$ such that for all $r \ge N$ the direct image $\pi_*F(r)= \pi_*(F \otimes O_{\mathbb{P}^n_S}(r))$ is locally free. ($\pi$ is the structure morphism $\mathbb{P}^n_S \to S$).
Claim: Then $F$ is flat over $S$.

Now the author leaves as exercise to show that the *converse*(!) of the above lemma holds as well: if $F$ is flat over $S$ then $\pi_*F(r)$ is locally free for all sufficiently large $r$.

Does anybody know how the proof of the converse works or where I can find it?

About the choice of suitable $N$ I conjecture that Serre's vanishing theorem may play an important role in the proof:

Let $A$ a ring and $F$ coherent on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$. Then for all $i \ge 1$ there exist $m_0$ with $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n_A, F(m))$ for all $m \ge m_0$.

But that's just my suspucion, not more since I otherwise not know how a candidate for $N$ can be found.

Comment: See for example Hartshorne, Theorem III.9.9. The idea is to use a Čech resolution and Serre vanishing.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: You mean that one which starts with "Let $T$ be an integral noetherian scheme. Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_T$ be a
closed subscheme... And the claim is that $X$ is flat over $T$ iff Hilbert polynomial $P_t$ is independent of $t$. Here is required that $T$ is integral, especially reduced, the book seems to work without it but thats subtile.

Comment: Another more important problem is how can we obtain a closed subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_T$ in the thereom from coherent sheaf $F$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_S$? $F$ induces a relative spectrum (a candidate for closed subscheme $X$ in the theorem) $X_F:=\operatorname{Spec}_S(F) \to S$ in well known way but is $X_F \subset \mathbb{P}^n_T$? 

$F$ is by definition only a $O_{\mathbb{P}^n_S}$-module not a $O_{\mathbb{P}^n_S}$-algebra. that is a priori there is no map  $O_{\mathbb{P}^n_S}=O_S[x_0,...x_n] \to F$ corresponding to $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n_T$. Do you know how relate $X$ and $F$?

Comment: This can be deduced from semicontinuity theorem . For sufficiently large $N$, higher direct images of $F(N)$ vanish. Then the direct image is locally free.

Comment: You're right, the reference doesn't cover the precise statement, but as @Mohan points out Thm III.12.11 does (together with Thm III.8.8).

Comment: I also think the (very short) proof of Thm III.9.9 (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) applies verbatim in this context, because that direction uses neither that $\mathscr F$ is the structure sheaf nor that $T$ is integral. In fact the first is not even stated as an assumption, and the second is only used for (iii)$\Rightarrow$(ii).

Comment: yes of course you are right, the proof in 9.9 solves the problem. sorry, as I wrote my last comment I didn't took a glance into theorem's proof of 9.9, only into it's statement.